# Calculating Matérn covariance in R returns matrices that are not positive definite

Tags: regression, r, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

In R, I am trying to calculate Matérn  covariance matrices whose inputs are randomly created distance matrices. However, I **often** end up getting covariance matrices that are not positive definite, which makes little sense.

At first, I had asked a version of this questions at StackOverflow, but a few comments made there reassured me that the code was not at fault. Additionally, I was told that while the Matérn covariance matrix obviously is, in theory, always positive definite, in practice it may not be.

At that point, I realized that this became a question more suited to CrossValidated. So, what I am trying to understand is **how to ensure the generation of a positive definite Matérn  covariance matrix in practice**.

Perhaps there are specific relations between the Matérn equation parameters that ensure that? Perhaps there are any other tricks - for example, [more general questions about ensuring positive definiteness in practice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182005/kernel-matrix-is-not-positive-definite) are usually answered by simply adding a tiny constant to the otherwise zero diagonals of the distance matrices - which does not solve my problem here.

For reference, here's how I generate a random distance matrix:

```
nrows <- 100
ncols <- 100
d <- matrix(runif(nrows*ncols, 0, 1), ncols, nrows)
# enforce symmetry:
d[lower.tri(d)] <- t(d)[lower.tri(d)]
diag(d) <- 0.000000000001 # instead of zero to avoid numerical issues
# check that we have a correct distance matrix:
range(d)
```

Then I follow this Wikipedia formula for Matérn  covariances:

[image]

```
# Calculate Marten covariance matrix:
sigma <- 1
v <- 3
p <- 5
term1 <- (2**(1-v))/(gamma(v))
term2 <- (sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p))**v
term3 <- besselK(sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p), nu = v)
m <- (sigma**2)*term1*term2*term3
```

However, when I check the eigenvalues of the Matérn covariance matrix, I see that it's not a positive definite matrix, as it should be:

```
g <- eigen(m, only.values=TRUE)
print(min(g$values)) # should be greater than zero, but instead is approx. -0.15
print(sum(g$values<0)/length(g$values)) # thus, this should be zero but instead is approx. 0.46
```

It surprises me that it is so easy to arrive at a non-positive definite Matérn covariance matrix, and I am then puzzled about how one may ensure positive definiteness.

Comment: What are the actual numerical values that are negative? Is it -100 or -0.00000000000000001?

Comment: @Sycorax running the code snippets above as-is shows that around 47% of the eigen values are negative each time, with the lowest eigen values usually around -0.15.

Comment: Marten is a repeated typo for Matérn. I have fixed your text but left your code untouched,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is not in the Matérn part. It is already in the "distance" part, i.e. with your matrix $d$. In your code, $d$ is just a (slightly fudged) symmetric random matrix with zeros on the diagonal and non-negative entries. But this is not enough to qualify the matrix as a distance matrix. In addition to the three properties (symmetric, zero diagonal and non-negative) for distances, you have the crucial triangle inequality. This is missing from your code. See the relevant section on  [Wikipedia's article on distance matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix#Metric_distance_matrix).

Comment: +1. But the code has numerous errors anyway.  `m` is not even a square matrix; when it is converted to one, floating point imprecision will likely create some tiny imaginary components in the eigenvalues (causing an error when calling `min`); the calculation of `m` for larger distances might be numerically unstable; and the eigenvalues should be checked either with `svd` or using `symmetric = TRUE` in the call to `eigen`.

Comment: @whuber I am really puzzled by your comment. In my code above `m` *is* a square matrix. And using `eigen(m, symmetric = TRUE)` changes nothing (as should be the case, since internally `eigen()` checks for symmetry anyways, hence making the parameter performance-oriented only).

Comment: This seems unlikely, why should your iid generated entries satisfy such a relation? Anyway, why don't you just sample some points, calculate their distances using `dist` and use this matrix for a test?

Comment: @hannah I ran your code before making that comment and tested my recommendations.  I warmly suggest you do the same!  Remember, you need to create an actual distance matrix... .  Use the `dist` function to do that.

Comment: @whuber thanks for doing so, and indeed g g's answer proved to be correct; the problem was in `d` disobeying triangle inequality, which I solved by using the `dist` function over vectors of data, as you both recommended. That said, for the sake of clarity, what puzzles me is your comment about `m` not being even a square matrix. I don't know what you tried exactly,  but I did run my code, of course, and a check `ncol(m) == nrow(m)` shows the code **does** generate a square `m`. Also, I did try your `eigen(m, symmetric = TRUE)`, which does nothing. See: https://onecompiler.com/r/428j7yjmp

Comment: @gg you were absolutely correct about my simulated distance matrices not obeying triangle inequality. However, oddly, calculating distance matrices with `dist` on some of my real datasets *also* generates distance matrices that do not obey triangle inequality - then resulting in Marten cov matrices that are not positive definite! And in that case, I can't ensure triangle inequality by design. I posted a different question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643696/distance-matrix-of-actual-dataset-doesnt-obey-triangle-inequality-leading-to-n) to not polute this one further.