# Distance matrix of actual dataset doesn't obey triangle inequality, leading to non-positive definite covariance matrix

Tags: regression, r, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

Yesterday [I asked a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643617/calculating-mat%C3%A9rn-covariance-in-r-returns-matrices-that-are-not-positive-defini?noredirect=1#comment1203072_643617) about why my randomly generated distance matrices were leading to Matérn covariance matrices that were not positive definite. The answer there called my attention to the fact that my simplistic way of generating randomly generated distance matrices was not ensuring that such matrices obeyed the triangle inequality. Indeed, enforcing that solved the problem.

However, what I realize now is that my real data is also leading to that same problem. That is, when calculating a distance matrix for the distances between rows in my dataset, I end up getting a distance matrix that... does not obey triangle inequality. And thus, leads to a Matérn covariance matrix that is not positive definite.

Here is a small subset (1000 rows) of my actual data (about 40,000 rows), which does reproduce the issue, uploaded to Filebin:

[actualdata.csv](https://filebin.net/nmzev577nq0m1j03)

Here is the illustration of what I am doing:

```
library(Rfast) # for fast calculation of distances and checking symmetry
library(fossil) # for checking triangle inequality

# Load subset of my actual data and calculate the distance matrix:
X <- read.csv("actualdata.csv")
d <- Rfast:Dist(X)
d[d==0] <- 0.000000000001 # instead of zero to avoid numerical issues

# Calculate Marten covariance matrix:
sigma <- 1
v <- 3
p <- 5
term1 <- (2**(1-v))/(gamma(v))
term2 <- (sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p))**v
term3 <- besselK(sqrt(2*v)*(abs(d)/p), nu = v)
m <- (sigma**2)*term1*term2*term3

# Check if covariance matrix is squared:
nrow(m) == ncol(m)

# Check eigenvalues of Marten covariance matrix:
g <- eigen(m, only.values=TRUE, symmetric = TRUE)
print(min(g$values)) # should be greter than zero, but isn't
print(sum(g$values<0)/length(g$values)) # thus, this should be zero, but isn't
```

Here is a set of checks of whether the `d` obeys all 4 properties of distance matrices:

```
# check that we have a correct distance matrix (warning: the triangle inequality checks may take a while):
Rfast::is.symmetric(d) # symmetric matrix? YES
sum(diag(d)!=0.000000000001)==0 # zero diagonal values? YES
min(d[row(d) == (col(d) - 1)])>0 # positive off-diagonal values? YES
fossil::tri.ineq(d) # obeys triangular inequality? NO (warning: this line is quite slow)
```

The problem is: because here the input dataset `X` is not simulated, I cannot force the distance matrix to obey triangle inequality by design. Therefore my question: in this case, what can be done to ensure the generation of a positive definite Matérn covariance matrix?

Comment: I just ran your code (except for `d[d==0] <- 0.000000000001`, which has nothing to do with computing a distance matrix). Testing non-negativity reveals an issue: `all(upper.tri(d) > 0.0)` returns `FALSE`, so there's at least one non-positive element in the upper triangular part of `d`. Moreover, examining `dim(unique(X))` reveals that there are 16 duplicated rows.

Comment: Matern covariances apply to Euclidean distances.  Thus, to create a distance matrix, (a) create a set of points in a Euclidean space and (b) compute their distances.  Here is an example in dimension `d` using `n` points uniformly distributed in $[0,1]^d:$ `d <- 2;
n <- 10;
p <- matrix(runif(d*n), n);
m <- as.matrix(dist(p))`  Besides being correct, it's even *simpler* than what you're doing.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for your insights. But your test is incorrect, since `upper.tri` returns TRUE/FALSE. It should have been `all(d[upper.tri(d)] > 0.0)`, not `all(upper.tri(d) > 0.0)`. Using the correct version returns `TRUE`. So there are none non-positive values in `d`. You are correct, however, that `X` has duplicate entries (as the full dataset also has). I tried adding a small random value to those entries, or even to the entire dataset, to force uniqueness, but that didn't help.

Comment: @whuber sure, but note that in this question I am using an existing, actual dataset. I am not generating it randomly.

Comment: No -- you are non-randomly altering the distances!  Get rid of the `0.000000000001` kludge and please provide a *reproducible example* of the problem you encounter.

Comment: @hannah My comment had a typo, but the typo doesn't change my conclusion. Fixing the typo and running `all(d[upper.tri(d)] > 0.0)` on the data you provided returns `FALSE`.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your help. But I was referring to your example in your 1st comment, that involved generating data randomly (you called it `p`) - which I don't do here. The code that I created and the `actualdata.csv` file, which is a subset of my real (non-randomly generated) dataset, **do** reproduce **exactly** the problem I am encountering. Now, if I get rid of `d[d==0] <- 0.000000000001`, the code generates `NaN` in the `m` diagonals, due to numerical issues. Surely, I can do `d[d==0] <- runif(sum(d==0), 0.000000000001, 0.0000001)` instead, but it doesn't solve the original question

Comment: @Sycorax oh, you mean if I don't do `d[d==0] <- 0.000000000001`? Sure, in that case we are left with a few zeroes off-diagonal due to `X` having repeated rows (this is a reality of the data, it does indeed have repeated rows). I must either (1) delete duplicated rows, (2) randomize a tiny number and put in those zeroes, or (3) randomize a tiny number to add to duplicate rows of `X`. Regardless, the diagonals of `d` will always require a tiny epsilon to avoid `NaN`s in the diagonals of `m`.

Comment: @hannah `d[d==0] <- 0.000000000001` is a kludge. If you truly **need** the duplicated data for some reason then you'll need to change the *covariance* matrix, not the distances. The answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/643743/22311 explains this in more detail: replace the removable discontinuity at 0. Using a kernel matrix of the form $K + \epsilon I$ is a standard approach for mitigating the numerical issues of identical or nearly-identical data.

Comment: @Sycorax ah, I see your point. This was very helpful - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't fudge the diagonal. Replace the final diagonal in `m` by sigma**2 to get rid of the (removable) singularity from 0 * Inf in the original expression.
2. Your parameter v=3 is unusual. Are you sure about this? Matérn-5/2 is with v=5/2.
3. Your data may be difficult there seem to be many identical coordinates, i.e. points are very close.
4. Scaling by p=5 decreases distances further.

The items above mean you will run into numerical difficulties for a large data set. Test this by starting with just a few points and increase to see when neg Eigenvalues will appear.

If you really need to fudge, add a small diagonal term. I.e. instead of using `m` as covariance use $m + \epsilon I$ for small $\epsilon>0$.

I have no idea what `tri.ineq` is doing. Most likely it runs into numerical difficulties as well. Don't bother with this test too much. A distance matrix is a distance matrix (up to pesky numerical issues).

You may also want to check issues against the simpler expressions for specific choices of `v`. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function#Simplification_for_%CE%BD_half_integer) In particular, the covariance with `v<-1/2` should be pretty robust.

Comment: Ah and a final remark: Don't call it *Marten*.

Comment: Fantastic, this was really helpful. Playing with the parameters proved to be enough, but the other insights were also quite helpful.